# Update not working

Tags: updates

Please help me to find solution for my Ubuntu update while I using `apt-get update` command, then error display as follows:

```
Err http://archive.ubuntu.com precise-updates/universe Sources
  Unable to connect to archive.ubuntu.com:http: [IP: 91.189.91.14 80]

E: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
```

Please give some solution for me.

Thanks for all!